# Moving world origin while the program is running

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm making a 3D game set in space with asteroids spinning around and various sectors to move through. Haven't had too many problems working on this till I started noticing something weird. I was implementing a very rudimentary collision system to hit asteroids, looks like this:

```
if (std::abs(glm::distance(glm::vec3(vec[i][12], vec[i][13], vec[i][14]), camera3D.getPosition())) <= 40.0f)
{
    std::cout << std::endl << "X:" << vec[i][12] << "    Y:" << vec[i][13] << "    Z:" << vec[i][14];
    std::cout << std::endl << "CAMERA POSITION:      " << "X:" << camera3D.getPosition().x << "    Y:" << camera3D.getPosition().y << "    Z:" << camera3D.getPosition().z;
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << "DISTANCE: " << glm::distance(glm::vec3(vec[i][12], vec[i][13], vec[i][14]), camera3D.getPosition());
    camera3D.changePosition(camera3D.getPosition() - glm::vec3(10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f));
}
```

where vec is a vector of glm::value_ptr fetching position coordinates from the model matrix of each asteroid:

```
std::vector<const float*> vec;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < meshModelMatrices2.size(); i++)
{
    if (alpha < 360.0f && alpha >= 0.0f)
    {
        alpha = 30.0f/100000.0f;

        meshModelMatrices2[i] *= glm::mat4
            (
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, cos(alpha), -sin(alpha), 0.0f,
            0.0f, sin(alpha), cos(alpha), 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
            );

        meshModelMatrices2[i] *= glm::mat4(1.0f);
    }

    vec.push_back(glm::value_ptr(meshModelMatrices2[i]));

    glUniformMatrix4fv(shaderModelMatrixIDm, 1, GL_FALSE, &meshModelMatrices2[i][0][0]);

    meshRenderer2.renderMesh();
}
```

The code works fine but I've noticed that the further I travel away from the world origin the more distances seem to become shorter, for example if I'm close to the origin a 40.0f distance from an asteroid means that I hit it even if I'm far away from it, but if I'm a lot farther away from the origin, say 10000.0f, then 40.0f distance means that I have to basically be inside the asteroid for the program to register it as a hit. Also, when I go farther and farther away from the origin my camera seems to slow down in its movement. I've read that this could be a problem caused by float point precision issues.

My question is: Is there a way to move the world origin together with my camera so that the camera position doesn't get too big and cause issues when I'm using it to calculate stuff?

PS: I think I've found a kind of workaround, basically in my vertex shader the actual gl_position of the meshes is not determined just by the model matrices, instead I have:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertexUV;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 vertexNormal;

uniform mat4 Perspective;
uniform mat4 CameraMatrix;
uniform mat4 ModelMatrix;
uniform vec3 LightPosition;

out vec2 UV;
out vec3 VertexWorldPosition;
out vec3 VertexToCamera;
out vec3 LightToCamera;
out vec3 VertexCameraNormal;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = Perspective * ModelMatrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
    UV = vec2(vertexUV.x, 1.0 - vertexUV.y);

    vec3 vertexCameraPosition = (CameraMatrix * ModelMatrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0)).xyz;
    VertexToCamera = (0,0,0) - vertexCameraPosition;

    vec3 lightCameraPosition = (CameraMatrix * vec4(LightPosition,1.0)).xyz;
    LightToCamera = VertexToCamera + VertexToCamera;

    VertexCameraNormal = (CameraMatrix * ModelMatrix * vec4(vertexNormal, 0)).xyz;

    VertexWorldPosition = (ModelMatrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0)).xyz;
}
```

so the position is determined by perspective matrix (which I'm getting from the camera) * the model matrix * a vec4(vertex position, 1.0) where vertex position is passed in from the layout in location 0 which is the buffer where the vertices for each mesh is contained. If I try to calculate this position outside of the shader I usually run in a memory leak so

Question 2: Is there a way to fetch this position from the vertex shader?

Comment: [Floating origin](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.471.7201&rep=rep1&type=pdf)?

Comment: Every coordinate in the same frame of reference uses the same origin. So if you move the origin, everything in that frame of reference moves equally, meaning zero relative motion happens. Moving an origin only has meaning when you are talking relatively about two or more frames of references. If you want to move which point corresponds to the origin relative to all your objects, you have to move all your objects instead.

Comment: mh, I get that, so I'd have to keep the normal world origin (which I use to decide the positions of the asteroids in the world) and then use the camera position as a center when I calculate the relative distance between camera and asteroid, so instead of using the coordinates of the asteroid I should use the coordinates of the asteroid - the coordinates of the camera in the glm::distance function?

Comment: @genpfault this seems like a possible solution but I'm too inexperienced to understand how to implement it from a code point of view